# Force Proximity Alert to use Network Provider

Tags: android, locationmanager

Is there any way to force proximity alerts to use only network provider?
I'm worried about battery drain.
Forcing proximity alerts to take more than 4 minutes to be fired would be a good solution too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A brilliant question,sadly though I dont think that would be possible , just had a look over the documentation as well , take note of this "Before API version 17, this method could be used with `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`. From `API version 17` and onward, this method requires `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission." So they are making it compulsory to pass in GPS Permission.

So currently there is no way of forcing it to use any particular provider.

There is a Enhancement Feature requested for the same , go ahead and star it to make Google implement it.

Link to Enhancement : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33151

Answer (score 1):

If your project does not require gps for other features you can set the SDK target to version 16:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

and require just the coarse location:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

so the proximity alerts will not check for the gps signal.
My point is that is the user keeps the GPS ON is conscius of the drain, remember that this is a toggle, you should consider it in the requirement of the app.